# U.S. check in Canadian dollars?

Tags: canada, check, payment

I reside in the U.S. and need to send money, via check, to a Canadian company payable in Canadian dollars. (This is the only payment method allowed.) What's the easiest way to accomplish this? Can I do this with my personal U.S. checking account?

Comment: Have you discussed with your bank? They can advise on how they would handle a cross-currency payment request. If the amount is under $1k, probably not worth it to seek out the best rate, but if it is more significant, paying an extra 1%+ depending on what your bank offers, would not be great.

Comment: Not sure if this is still standard practice, but I could just write $1000 CAD (in the box, and "One Thousand Canadian Dollars" on the spelled out line) on a personal check and banks would deal with it, not the most favorable exchange rates, but got the job done.

Comment: My bank used to allow me to write Canadian cheques in US dollars, and it worked, but I would be really surprised if a random US bank would do this. Why can't you do a wire transfer from your bank or use a service like TransferWise? I am always suspicious when people can take payment only one way, especially since depositing US dollar cheques into Canadian bank accounts is trivially normal.